# Determine $k$ so that the function is continuous

Tags: continuity

> $$y=\begin{cases}\Large{\frac{\left(e^{(k+2)x}-1\right)}{5x}}&x<0\\x^2+5k-2&x\ge0\end{cases}$$

Applying the continuity theorem, I tried this 
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\left(\frac{\left(e^{(k+2)x}-1\right)}{5x}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x^2+5k-2)$$
And then seeing that the first limit was irrational I used L'Hôpital's rule and I got this 
$$\frac{\left((k+2)e^{(k+2)x}\right)}5$$
After that I just replaced the $x$ term with $0$ and found that $k = 1/2$.

Did I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's correct.

$$\frac{k+2}{5}=5k-2$$

$$k+2=25k-10$$

$$12=24k$$

$$k=\frac12$$